# o programa está imprimindo lixo de memoria, onde estaria o erro?

Tags: c

/* Faça um programa que recebe dois valores inteiros, um de limite inferior e outro de limite superior. Sua função deve imprimir todos os valores no intervalo fechado definido. */

```
int main()
{
int max, min, n;
scanf("%i %i", &max, &min);
 n = max - min;
int vet[1000];

printf("valor max %i, e o valor min %i\n\n", max, min);
printf("os numeros entre o max e min sao:\n");
vet[1000] = funcao(max, min);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
 printf("%i   ", vet[i]);
}
 return 0;
}

int funcao(max,min){
int vet[1000];

for (int i=0; max >= min; max--){
 vet [i] = max;
 i++;
if (max == min){
return vet;
}}}
```

Comment: Você retorna vet mas atribui a um elemento de um array (um inteiro).